# YOLOv4 custom function doesnt detect video while running on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, yolov4

im using YOLOv4 custom function from the AI guys's repo. Everything works flawlessly, including convert weights file to pb file, run detection on both image and videos, then this error shows up on both pc and colab:

- When i use only CPU, detection runs fine on both image and video data
- When i use GPU, detections only runs on image. When run on videos, it still runs, but doesnt detect anything. I assume that the detection only runs on the first frame, but not on the rest ones.
- Here is the console log when run video detect on CPU :

> 2021-05-01 11:19:05.173287: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.268691: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.269701: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.279142: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.279180: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (76ac529fe3d6): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.325497: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> True:  False
> 2021-05-01 11:19:07.328773: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> Current threshold:  0.5
> 2021-05-01 11:19:23.595602: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
> 2021-05-01 11:19:23.658932: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2299995000 Hz
> FPS: 0.77
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.69, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 389.0, 392.0, 397.0
> FPS: 2.60
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.68, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 389.0, 392.0, 397.0
> FPS: 2.38
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.69, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 389.0, 392.0, 396.0
> FPS: 2.51
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.89, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 389.0, 391.0, 397.0
> FPS: 2.48
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.90, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 390.0, 391.0, 397.0
> FPS: 2.52
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.90, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 380.0, 390.0, 391.0, 397.0
> FPS: 2.64
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.87, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 379.0, 391.0, 390.0, 398.0
> FPS: 2.59
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.76, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 378.0, 392.0, 390.0, 399.0
> FPS: 2.64
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.75, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 377.0, 392.0, 390.0, 400.0
> FPS: 2.61
> Object found: Noentry, Confidence: 0.71, BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): 377.0, 393.0, 389.0, 401.0
> FPS: 2.58
> FPS: 2.66
> FPS: 2.52
> FPS: 2.50
> FPS: 2.57
> FPS: 2.59
> FPS: 2.60
> FPS: 2.75
> FPS: 2.57
> FPS: 2.77

- Here is the console log when run video detection on GPU ( im sorry if log is a little bit too long )

> 2021-05-01 10:32:33.098862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.935938: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.936785: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.953709: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.954371: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
> pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 6.0
> coreClock: 1.3285GHz coreCount: 56 deviceMemorySize: 15.90GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 681.88GiB/s
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.954406: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.957049: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.957129: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.958917: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.959305: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.961111: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.961867: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.962058: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.962151: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.962729: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:34.963310: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.006935: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007063: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007689: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
> pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 6.0
> coreClock: 1.3285GHz coreCount: 56 deviceMemorySize: 15.90GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 681.88GiB/s
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007719: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007781: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007803: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007839: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007859: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007881: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007903: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.007991: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.008575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.009095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.009140: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.503454: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.503505: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.503515: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.503690: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.504369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.504897: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.505452: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14975 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0)
> True:  False
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.506749: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.506845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507388: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
> pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 6.0
> coreClock: 1.3285GHz coreCount: 56 deviceMemorySize: 15.90GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 681.88GiB/s
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507472: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507485: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507524: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.507582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508113: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508630: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508640: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508647: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.508710: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.509240: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
> 2021-05-01 10:32:35.509738: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14975 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0)
> Current threshold:  0.5
> 2021-05-01 10:32:50.238825: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
> 2021-05-01 10:32:50.290412: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2199995000 Hz
> 2021-05-01 10:32:50.932916: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
> 2021-05-01 10:32:51.960900: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
> 2021-05-01 10:32:52.189146: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
> FPS: 0.41
> FPS: 23.86
> FPS: 23.61
> FPS: 24.18
> FPS: 23.84
> FPS: 23.82
> FPS: 24.36
> FPS: 23.82
> FPS: 24.10
> FPS: 24.39
> FPS: 24.17
> FPS: 24.09
> FPS: 24.54
> FPS: 23.93
> FPS: 23.35
> FPS: 24.02
> FPS: 24.11
> FPS: 24.48
> FPS: 24.10
> FPS: 24.29
> FPS: 24.46
> FPS: 24.48
> FPS: 23.62
> FPS: 23.79
> FPS: 23.76
> FPS: 24.01
> FPS: 24.43
> FPS: 23.52
> FPS: 24.46
> FPS: 24.13
> FPS: 24.11
> FPS: 23.79
> FPS: 24.62
> FPS: 24.32
> FPS: 24.06
> FPS: 24.51
> FPS: 24.46
> FPS: 24.40
> FPS: 24.48
> FPS: 24.62
> Video end

At first i assume that my GPU is not strong enough ( GTX 1050 mobile), but it happens even when running on colab pro with Tesla V100
I appreciate any helps.

Comment: You said "from this repo", but didn't say what it was. I think it would be better to raise an Issue at their repo.

Comment: my bad. I edited it .

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how I solved it. The problem is caused by TensorFlow's version. Downgrade the version to 2.3.0.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
```